# AdMob banners cause high CPU usage

Tags: android, admob, cpu-usage

I have the latest AdMob version (6.4.1), and when I show some banner its cause my CPU to start sweating (Not to mention the battery :S ).

I am destroying the AdView when I leave the activity, but when the activity is started it takes about 20% of CPU usage.

Is there any way to fix it? Why the CPU usage is so high when the ads are shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Having test my app with 2 different implementations of AdMob **I found
>   that implementing it via java code and not XML is match lighter for
>   the app.**
>
> **Update No1:**
>
> You can also add custom listeners to destroy after some time and
>   recreate in order to handle it even better. Serverside there is also a
>   parameter telling the app ad how soon should ask for a new ad, I am
>   not sure if it exist in all cases but it is there for DFP accounts.
>
> A nice suggested way to implement the ad is that:
>
> ```
> new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
> @Override
> public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
>   if (!isBeingDestroyed) {
>       final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
>       final AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
>       adView.loadAd(adRequest);
>   }
> }).sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);
> ```
>
> also do not forget to call `adView.destroy()` onDestroy()
>   activity or when you do not want it any more!
>
> The above way is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14683378/1932105) with many useful memory releases!

the complete answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14683378/1932105

please use the search next time. Good luck