# admob banner use too much memory

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I just added admob ads to my app "Banner ads" 
and i notice its using  more than 30MG i already searched for solution her in stack-overflow and other web sites and i didn't find  any useful solution i already using the last SDK version and here is the version of ads library

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
```

by the  way i am using Kotlin .
it's not duplicated because i already take look of the most of question and answers here and no one worked for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AdMob memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584002/android-admob-memory-usage)

Comment: no its not duplicate please remove your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

@NikolayElenkov Answered this question relatively well in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584002/android-admob-memory-usage)
He goes on to basically say that it's due to how complex the object is. Additionally, due to the fact that ads come in various types (HTML, Videos, Images, etc.), they will vary in the amount of memory they use. Furthermore, due to it being a closed source SDK provided by Google, there is really nothing you can do about it unless you wanted to create your own ad hosting SDK.